# How to use inverse dynamics controller on under-actuated systems

Tags: drake

I'm trying to use Drake's inverse dyanmics controller on an arm with a floating base, and based on [this discussion](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13718) it seems like the most straightforward way to go about this is to use two separate plants since the controller only supports fully actuated systems.

Following [Python bindings error when adding two plants to a scene graph in pyDrake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68460170/python-bindings-error-when-adding-two-plants-to-a-scene-graph-in-pydrake/68470928#68470928), I attempted to create two plants using the following code:

```
def register_plant_with_scene_graph(scene_graph, plant):
    plant.RegsterAsSourceForSceneGraph(scene_graph)
    builder.Connect(
        plant.get_geometry_poses_output_port(),
        scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(plant.get_source_id()),
    )
    builder.Connect(
        scene_graph.get_query_output_port(),
        plant.get_geometry_query_input_port(),
    )

builder = DiagramBuilder()
scene_graph = builder.AddSystem(SceneGraph())
plant_1 = builder.AddSystem(MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.0))
register_plant_with_scene_graph(scene_graph, plant_1)
plant_2 = builder.AddSystem(MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.0))
register_plant_with_scene_graph(scene_graph, plant_2)
```

which produced the error

```
AttributeError: 'MultibodyPlant_[float]' object has no attribute 'RegsterAsSourceForSceneGraph'
```

Which seems odd because according to the documentation, [the function should exist](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a4a6d28ce9c8119bee923e827eb6f02ed).

Is this function available in the python bindings for drake? Also, more broadly, is this the correct way to approach using the inverse dynamics controller on a free-floating manipulator?

Answer (score 0):

Inverse dynamics takes desired positions, velocities, and accelerations and computes the required torques.  If your robot has a floating base, then you cannot accept arbitrary acceleration commands.  For instance the total center of mass of your robot will be falling according to gravity; any acceleration that does not satisfy this requirement will not have a feasible solution to the inverse dynamics.  I think there must be something more that we need to understand about your problem formulation.

Often when people ask this question, they are thinking of a robot that is relying on contact forces in addition to generalized force/torques in order to achieve the requested accelerations. In that case, the problem needs to include those contact forces as decision variables, too.  Since contact forces have unilateral constraints (e.g. feet cannot pull on the ground), and friction cone constraints, this inverse dynamics problem is almost always formulated as a quadratic program.  For instance, as in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6907230?casa_token=riegCyViA3wAAAAA:QDcowo-XY5si5hLKOaE-Dk7ji2QH87HStyisDrgFUmaCqDcVXhPgtlPA3ej2Q-9XihU3T65p_Q).  We don't currently provide that QP formulation in Drake, but it is not hard to write it against the `MathematicalProgram` interface.  And we do have some older code that was removed from Drake (since it wasn't actively developed) that we can point you to if it helps.

Comment: That sounds good, having an inverse dynamics controller that can account for contact forces would be ideal. Could you point me to the older code you mentioned?

Comment: Check out the qp_inverse_dynamics and associated InstantaneousQpController in e.g. https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/9855